# how to add pause on hover ( jquery )

Tags: jquery

Here is the code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testimonials .slide');
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#testimonials .slide').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            if($(this).next('li.slide').size()){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(2000);
            }
            else{
                $('#testimonials .slide').eq(0).fadeIn(2000);
            }
        });
    },1000);    
});
```

This applies to a ul list , and would like to add pause on hover. Any suggestions. ?

Comment: what do you mean by "pause"? Can you provide us with a example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 6):

You need to save the object that is returned by `setInterval`, and then you can pass it to `clearInterval` to stop it from occurring again.

Here is some sample code that should get you something like what you are after:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = function() {
        $('#testimonials .slide').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            if($(this).next('li.slide').size()){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(2000);
            }
            else{
                $('#testimonials .slide').eq(0).fadeIn(2000);
            }
        });
    };

    // save an object so that I can start and stop this as we go
    var interval = setInterval(slider, 1000);

    // when the user hovers in, clear the interval; if they hover out,
    // restart it again
    $('#testimonials .slide').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, function() {
        interval = setInterval(slider, 1000);
    });
});
```

Note that it's not clear to me *what* exactly the user hovers over to get the interval to stop, so I assumed you wanted `$('#testimonials .slide')` to do that. If not, just change that part to whatever you need.

Comment: I've been searching around for this for a while now.  I was searching for the wrong stuff.  I'm glad I found this!

Comment: Can you please assist with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598240/how-to-modify-script-to-make-carousel-continuous-and-pause-on-hover