# jquery fadein fadeout with pause on hover

Tags: jquery

I am using following jquery code to fadein / fadeout testimonials. But continuous loop make it difficult to read if testimonial is long. How can i add pause on hover in this script?

jQuery code:

```
$('.testimonials .testimonial').hide();
function fadeContent() {
    $(".testimonials .testimonial:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
        fadeContent();
    });
}
fadeContent();
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="testimonials">
    <div class="testimonial"><p>First testimonial</p></div>
    <div class="testimonial"><p>Second testimonial</p></div>
    <div class="testimonial"><p>Third testimonial</p></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c7eRY/

Comment: HTML code is now added to question.

Comment: on hover you want to pause the slider ?

Comment: I found answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039952/how-to-add-pause-on-hover-jquery

Answer (score -1):

I would consider using setInterval to repeat the fades rather than the recursive call you currently have.  Then on hover you could cancel the interval (with clearInterval) and .show() the hovered object (to make sure it doesn't pause on hidden).  When you stop hovering, start the interval again.

Comment: I didn't want to spend the time to write/test a complete function but thought I could still be helpful by giving him a new idea that would help him find or come up with a solution.  And it looks like the solution he found was actually pretty similar to what I described.